# Collinearity in n dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, algorithms

What is the best way to check if $m$ points are collinear in $n$ dimensions?

I mean I have

> $p_1=(3, 4, 5, 2),\quad p_2=(6, 3, 4, 2),\quad p_3=(5, 3, 5,  6),\quad p_4=(4, 2, 7, 4)$

or

> $p_1=(1, 6, 2, 7, 7),\quad p_2=(1, 3, 6, 7, 2),\quad p_3=(6, 2, 5, 2, 8),\quad p_4=(8, 5, 3, 2)$

Are they collinear? What is universal way to do it?

Comment: **Hint:** use the vectorial equation for a line.

Comment: *Note*: your last point $p_4$ has only 4 coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

Take any pair of input vectors which are not identical. Their difference is the direction of the line, and either of these two is a start point.

For all other points, subtract the start point and check whether the result is an exact multiple of the direction vector.